# crystal report -- Failed to load database information -- on client PC

Tags: windows, vb.net, oracle11g, crystal-reports

im using vb.net, oracle and crystal report , i have two reports one have connection "database Expert --- project data --- DataSet1, working fine no issue , another one have connection "database Expert --- My Connection --- Sureguide" this one giving me this msg  [Failed to load database information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KogcK.png) ,.... what should i do to resolve this problem

[the one is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zie4f.png)

[the reports which not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyUdR.png)

> If Not sgcnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
>               sgcnn.Open()
>           End If
>
> ```
>     Dim rpt As New RptAccountsChart() 'The report created
>     'Dim rpt As New RptChartOfAccountsrpt 'The report created.
>
>     Try
>
>         Dim comd As New OracleCommand("select * from ACCOUNT_JV order by ACCOUNT_CODE,HEAD_CODE,JV_CODE ", sgcnn)
>
>         Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter(comd)
>
>         Dim dt As New DataTable()
>         da.Fill(dt)
>         rpt.SetDataSource(dt)
>
>         CRVChartOfAccounts.ReportSource = rpt
>
>         rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("sureguide_admin", "ajaz661")
>
>         rpt.Refresh()
>
>     Catch ex As Exception
>
>         MsgBox(ex.Message)
>
>     End Try
> ```

Comment: Can you access the code? Do you set database from code behind or user interface has prompt for this?

Comment: yes i can access and code behind the form ... i made connection in main module then call it on the form where crystalreportviewer placed. and i also have connection "database Expert --- My Connection --- Sureguide" on rpt .....

Comment: Please post the code. May be something is missing.

Comment: Can you check what is the difference in code from the one which is working? Or the working report has the similar code only database information is different?

Comment: no difference in code, The difference is in report level – the one is working  have connection "database Expert --- project data --- DataSet1, and the other reports which msg "crystal window form viewer" ----"Failed to load database information" have have connection "database Expert --- My Connection --- Sureguide"

Comment: i just added 2 screen plz view , how i can solve the problem without re-create the reports.